# Save data generated from Rstudio to git automatically

Tags: git, rstudio, commit

I have an R function that generates a data from, say, an API.

And i want to save the generated data automatically on my Git repo.

I have some logic like below:

```
git_commit = function(a,b) {
    x = get_data(a,b)  
    return(x)
    f(git_commit.sh)
}
```

So will a function like this work as I want, which can save the generated data, `x`, to Git? If yes, then what the `f(git_commit.sh)` should be? I suppose it is a line that deals with the git_commit.sh, which I have below:

```
#!/bin/sh
read -p "Commit description: " desc
git add . && \
git add -u && \
git commit -m "$desc" && \
git push Ian
```

Thanks in advance! Any ideas and corrections welcome!

Comment: When you say "automatically", do you have some events in mind? For instance, each time you commit? Or each time you run some test or whatever? In the former case, you could use a [pre-commit hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks)